# If html content is not enough to overflow y, stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

This image probably explains best.

[image: the problem with my chat]

I have this chat functionality, very basic at the moment. When there's is enough text to overflow the page, it gives the behavior I want. The most recent message is just above the message input at the bottom. However, when there is only a few messages, the messages that exist are at the top and it leaves a big empty space between it and the message input.

Here is the relevant HTML. The text input is just `position: fixed` at the bottom of the screen and there's a `bottom-margin` on `#message_outer_parent` to keep it above it.

```
<div id="message_outer_parent">
  <div id="message_content_parent"><div class="message_parent">
    <span class="message_icon glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color: #e21bcb" "=""></span>
    <span class="message_username">whatever</span>
    <span class="message_message">test text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="message_input_parent">
    <form id="new_message" onsubmit="return submit_new_message()">
      <input type="text" name="message_input" class="form-control" id="message_input" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="">
      <!-- submit button positioned off screen -->
      <input name="submit_message" type="submit" id="submit_message" value="true" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the messages just above the message input, even when there's only a few messages. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [Here's something](https://jsfiddle.net/hz0a2j9c/) that can help you.

Comment: That's a perfect solution. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Fixed position` on the other div.

```css
#message_input_parent {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
}

#message_outer_parent {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 30px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*padding and border won't increase height and width*/
}
```

```html
<div id="message_outer_parent">
  <div id="message_content_parent"><div class="message_parent">
    <span class="message_icon glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color: #e21bcb"></span>
    <span class="message_username">whatever</span>
    <span class="message_message">test text</span>
  </div>

  <div id="message_input_parent">
    <form id="new_message" onsubmit="return submit_new_message()">
      <input type="text" name="message_input" class="form-control" id="message_input" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="">
      <!-- submit button positioned off screen -->
      <input name="submit_message" type="submit" id="submit_message" value="true" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2. Using `flexbox`

```css
#message_input_parent {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
}

#message_outer_parent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 5px 5px 30px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

*{margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="message_outer_parent">
  <div id="message_content_parent"><div class="message_parent">
    <span class="message_icon glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color: #e21bcb"></span>
    <span class="message_username">whatever</span>
    <span class="message_message">test text</span>
  </div>

  <div id="message_input_parent">
    <form id="new_message" onsubmit="return submit_new_message()">
      <input type="text" name="message_input" class="form-control" id="message_input" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="">
      <!-- submit button positioned off screen -->
      <input name="submit_message" type="submit" id="submit_message" value="true" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```